# Show a topmost popup attached to a control in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

I'm trying to implement a callout that can pop up from a user control that's created in XAML and is derived from `ContentView`. The control itself is a circle that should take up a certain space on a page and the callout should float above all other controls. We're only targeting Windows at the moment.

I've set a high `ZIndex` when using the control and I've used a Grid with `IsClippedToBounds="False"` and draw the callout over the boundaries of the grid using `LineSegment`s.

If I now use this control inside a `CollectionView`, the callout always gets clipped and ends up under the collection view header. I've tried setting the `Zindex` on all elements of the collection: the cell, the collection view itself and the view the collection view is contained in but I can't seem to be able to prevent this behavior.

Does anyone have an idea how to handle a case like this?

[image: Information callout]

Comment: You may need an `AbsoluteLayout` wrapping the CollectionView. With the Callout a child of that AbsoluteLayout; not buried in a custom control in a row of the collectionview. Use an event handler or Messenger to communicate with the Callout. Might need custom handler per platform to get pixel-level accuracy in positioning relative to the target control.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Short answer: this has no place in the parent, it should be top element. You need to find the position for that particular list item, and use it to display the popup at the right position.

If you expect this to follow the item when you scroll, you will have hard time implementing it.

(At your place, I would "get inspiration" from here: https://github.com/LuckyDucko/Mopups)

About this trim. First, it is expected. Second, you will have hard time customizing it. Third, it does not behave consistent across IOS and Android. I had hard time to make most round corners render properly. I gave up on some controls ideas because of that.

But if you want, you can keep trying...